# Passing authentication tokens between 2 websites?

Tags: authentication, ldap, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Our company has two websites. Both websites have their own subdomains (on same domain). Both websites are using the same LDAP server for authentication.

Is there a way to authenticate users only once, and allow the (authenticated) user to access either website so that we don't have to login in to each site separately? For example, I'm logged in to siteA.domain.org, then I click on siteB.domain.org -- in this case I wouldn't be prompted to login to siteB.domain.org because I'm already authenticated to siteA.domain.org.

Comment: Tried setting the cookie for ***.domain.org**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add some info to your question regarding how you're doing your authentication. OAuth is an authorisation protocol, with a side-effect of authentication in some circumstances. So (for example) in Google OAuth, the user signs in to **Google**, not your website. Your website can test if the user is signed in to Google, and if so, obtain an access/id token to know who the user is.

So it all depends how your site is choosing to handle "login"